# Django Rest Framework and a custom OAuth2 Server

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

We have an identity server that implements the OAuth2 protocol for all of our various applications so that a single identity for our users can be shared across those apps. I'm having trouble thinking how I would connect my apps with the server securely.

Here are the components of our stack that we have right now:

1. A single page javascript app that calls our API (app.mydomain.com)
2. The API is a Django Rest Framework API (api.mydomain.com)
3. The Identity server (auth.mydomain.com)

Here's what I'm thinking:

1. The javascript app POSTs to `api.mydomain.com/login` with the username and password entered by a user on the form and, in the header, passes along the `clientId` for that application which is defined on the identity server as a registered application.
2. `api.mydomain.com/login` makes a request to `auth.mydomain.com` requesting a password grant for the user and passes along the clientId and clientSecret (let's say on the api side, we know how to map a clientId to its secret).
3. If the username, password, clientId, and clientSecret all check out, `auth.mydomain.com` responds with an access token. The identity server responds with an access token, refresh token, etc. Something like

`{
    "access_token": "someRequestToken",
    "refresh_token": "someRefreshToken",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}`

4. Any future calls to `api.mydomain.com` will be made with the `Bearer XXX` token provided in the request - the custom authentication module we have on our API can read the token and check its validity with the identity server on each request.

My question is - how could I plug this into the SessionMiddleware and SessionAuthentication so that we don't need to submit the token on each request to the API and so the API won't need to check with the identity server for validity on each request?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing OAuth2, the token MUST be passed with every request. The entire security of OAuth2 depends on it. You also mentioned you are using REST. Sessions are an absolute no no with REST.